# Generating Data Using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate 500 records using CTE, my output table should be something like below

| TEST | DESCRIPTION | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TEST1 | DESC1 | 1 |
| TEST2 | DESC2 | 2 |
| TEST3 | DESC3 | 3 |
| TEST4 | DESC4 | 4 |

I struggling with how to create it with cte as it has to be wrapped inside view

i created temp table its working fine but i wasnt able to wrap it inside view

i tried the following code

```
with cte1 as (
CREATE TABLE #code1(TEST,DESCRIPTION)
declare @TEST int
set @TEST = 1 
While @TEST <= 500
Begin 
    
    Insert Into #code1(TEST,DESCRIPTION) 
    values ('TEST' + CAST(@TEST as varchar(100)),'DESC' + CAST(@TEST as varchar(100)))
   Print @TEST
   Set @TEST = @TEST + 1
End

)
```

I think I am doing it in the wrong way, can anyone give me any suggestions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INSERT...SELECT` syntax is all off. Start by creating the table normally, then `INSERT` the rows.

The best way to generate a lot of rows is to use a tally function. [Itzik Ben-Gan's cross-join](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) is great, here is a simplified version of it, good for up to 65,536 rows

```sql
WITH
    L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c 
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
    L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B ),
    L2 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B ),
    Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
              FROM L2 )

  INSERT #code1 (TEST, DESCRIPTION, ID)
  SELECT TOP(500)
    CONCAT('TEST', rownum) AS TEST,
    CONCAT('DESC', rownum) AS DESCRIPTION,
    rownum AS ID
  FROM Nums;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stored procedure to achieve a similar result:

SP Code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc00()
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE code1 (TEST VARCHAR(20),DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(30),ID INT);
        SET @TEST = 1;
        WHILE @TEST <= 500 DO
            INSERT INTO code1
            VALUES (CONCAT('TEST',@TEST),CONCAT('DESC',@TEST),@TEST);
            SET @TEST = @TEST + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SELECT * FROM code1;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then let's execute the stored procedure by using CALL() statement:

CALL Proc00();

It returns:

[image: GGG]

...............

[image: FGDSSSDDDD]

Comment: I Cant upvote, hence writing in the comment as all the response are good, not even helped me but widen my prospective for the problem. Thanks again Charlieface , Ozan Sen.

Comment: Hi @Mark . You're welcome. I am pleased to hear that my post has been useful for you. Stay Safe. 